# How to use insert parameter with textbox text in listview

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am trying to use my `SqlDataSource` to enter items into the database with values from a TextBox, however nothing is inserting.

Here is my `SqlDataSource`:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SectionDataSource" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ORHP_Dev03182014ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT SectionItem FROM Core.SectionItem_Lkup">               
</asp:SqlDataSource>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SectionIDDataSource" runat="server " ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ORHP_Dev03182014ConnectionString %>" InsertCommand="INSERT INTO Core.SectionItem_Lkup(SectionItemID, SectionItem, SectionItemLabel) VALUES (@SectionID, @SectionItem, @SectionItemLabel)" SelectCommand="  SELECT MAX(SectionItemID) + 1 AS SectionItemID FROM [ORHP_Dev03182014].[Core].[SectionItem_Lkup]" OnInserting="Section_OnInserted">
    <InsertParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="SectionID" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="SectionItem" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="SectionItemLabel" />
    </InsertParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Here are the Textboxes in the listview:

```
<InsertItemTemplate>
    <tr style="">
        <td>
            <asp:Button ID="InsertButton" runat="server" CommandName="Insert" Text="Insert" On />
            <asp:Button ID="CancelButton" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Clear" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <div style="font-size: .8em;">
            <asp:FormView ID="SectionIDFormView" runat="server" DataKeyNames="SectionItemID" DataSourceID="SectionIDDataSource">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="SectionIDLabel" runat="server" Text="SectionID" Font-Bold="true" Font-Size="1.2em" />
                <asp:TextBox ID="SectionIDTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("SectionItemID") %>' Width="50px" />
                <asp:Label ID="SectionItemLabel" runat="server" Text="SectionItem" Font-Bold="true" Font-Size="1.2em" />
                <asp:TextBox ID="SectionItemTextBox" runat="server" Text="" />
                <asp:Label ID="SectionItemSubLabel" runat="server" Text="SectionItem Label" Font-Bold="true" Font-Size="1.2em" />
                <asp:TextBox ID="SectionItemLabelTextBox" runat="server" Text="" />
            </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:FormView>
        </div>
      </td>
   </tr>
</InsertItemTemplate>
```

Here is my code behind:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=RCK-HRSA-DB01;Initial Catalog=ORHP_Dev03182014;User ID=userid;Password=password"))
{
    try
    {
        SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Core.SectionItem_Lkup(SectionItemID, SectionItem, SectionItemLabel) VALUES (" + SectionIDTextBox.Text + ", " + SectionItemTextBox.Text + ", " + SectionItemLabelTextBox.Text + ")");
        connection.Open();
        cmd1.Connection = connection;
        cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: One thing I notice is that your FormView's data source is set to `SectionIDDataSource` and your SqlDataSource's ID is `SectionDataSource`. Are all your SqlDataSources matched up correctly?

Comment: @BubbleHearth That may be the problem. I am using two datasources through this part. However, I needed SectionIDDataSource to get the SectionItemID. Should I put the Insert Commands into the other data source or both?

Comment: Well I was going to say your next issue is going to be your ControlParameters. They use controls that are contained within data bound controls, so the IDs won't be as you have them listed anyway. I would suggest that you take the inserts out of the SqlDataSource and do it in your codebehind instead - in the ItemCommand handler like you had started for example.

Comment: @BubbleHearth Am I on the right track? See code changes above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are going to run into when going the route you are going is finding the controls for your ControlParameters. When a control is within a data bound control, the ID isn't what you declare it as. You can see this when you view the source on your page after it has rendered.

For FormViews, it's generally comes out to being something like `SectionIDFormView$SectionIDLabel`, which obviously isn't the same as `SectionIDLabel`. So using a ControlParameter like so may work for you:

```
<InsertParameters>
    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="SectionIDFormView$SectionIDLabel"
        Direction="Input" Name="SectionID" PropertyName="Text" />
</InsertParameters>
```

As an alternative, when the `Insert` button on the ListView is clicked, handle the click event and do the insert within there. Take the inserting away from the SqlDataSource all together.

```
protected void ListView1_ItemCommand(object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Insert")
    {
        ListViewItem item = ListView1.InsertItem;
        FormView SectionIDFormView = (FormView)item.FindControl("SectionIDFormView");
        TextBox SectionIDTextBox = (TextBox)SectionIDFormView.FindControl("SectionIDTextBox");
        //Find your other controls
        //Do your insert
    }
}
```

Try using a parameterized query:

```
SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Core.SectionItem_Lkup(SectionItemID, SectionItem, SectionItemLabel) VALUES (@SectionItemID, @SectionItem, @SectionItemLabel)");

cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SectionItemID", SectionIDTextBox.Text);
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SectionItem", SectionItemTextBox.Text);
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SectionItemLabel", SectionItemLabelTextBox.Text);
```

Comment: How do I handle the click event? I put OnItemCommand="SectionListView_OnItemCommand" in the ListView properties but it never reaches the SectionListView_OnItemCommand method

Comment: and you are clicking a button within your ListView that has a `CommandName` attribute set?

Comment: Yes the button is in the insert template and the Command Name is Insert. Do I need an Onclick method for the button?

Comment: No, you shouldn't need it. That should work. But for the sake of getting it working you could add the same code (except the condition) into a new OnClick handler.

Comment: For the other controls I received an Invalid column name for the data inserted into the textbox. Do I need to include '@' for the parameters?

Comment: Use a parameterized query instead. It is much safer. See my edit above.